# IF EXISTS.... DROP not working in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am stuck with the following stored procedure where I can't seem to get the `IF EXISTS` and `DROP` parts to work, leading to a failure in the `SELECT INTO` part.

Both database A and database B are on the same server, I have full permissions in both databases. The stored procedure is in database A.

I have copied the `IF EXISTS` syntax from somewhere (can't remember where) so I don't really understand the structure of it. I gathered the problem lies in the `IF EXISTS` statement because when I try and execute `IF EXISTS` component of the stored procedure, I get something if I have selected DatabaseB in the top left-hand corner drop-down box in Management Studio but if I have DatabaseA selected in there, I get nothing.

I have also tried to run similarly structured stored procedures in DatabaseA (where there is an IF EXISTS and DROP statements pointing to DatabaseB followed by a `SELECT INTO from DatabaseA into DatabaseB`) and I have got some to work before, while some others failed. I cant seem to pinpoint what is causing it to work sometimes and sometimes not.

```
USE [DatabaseA]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--DROP TABLE A if exists--
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects  
           WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'DatabaseB.dbo.TableA') AND type IN (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE DatabaseB.dbo.TableA

--Select INTO TableA on DatabaseB--
SELECT *
INTO DatabaseB.dbo.TableA
FROM DatabaseA.dbo.TableA
```

Comment: Change `USE[DatabaseA]` to `[DatabaseB]`, Basically you are searching the tableA from the `DatabaseB` in `DatabaseA` that's why issue is happening. Or if you dont want to change the `USE` then you can do the `DatabaseB.sys.objects` instead of `sys.objects`. I am assuming that you have both database on same server. If servers are different then you have to include server name as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it now. Although I do want the stored procedure to be created in DatabaseA, not DatabaseB. Oops, sorry just read the rest of your response - I will specify DatabaseB in sys objects. Thanks, will get back to you.

Comment: If thats the case then change the `DatabaseB.sys.objects` instead of `sys.objects`

Comment: HALLELLJAH!! Thank you so much! Learnt something that was a straightforward fix. Should have come here right away instead of scratching my head for the past week.

Comment: Oh can I ask a followup question re stored proceudures? Can I execute a stored procedure within another stored procedure?

Comment: yup you can do that. Just google it there are lots of questions related to that on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use `if object_id('databaseB.dbo.TableA') is not null` instead of the exists check to avoid having to fully qualify sys.objrcts.

Comment: Plus it's a lot less typing. I'm right there with you.